# Why are most enamelled cast iron dutch ovens only rated up to 400-450°F?

Tags: cast-iron, dutch-oven

I've been investigating getting an enamelled cast iron dutch oven and am surprised to find that most of them don't recommend going over 400-450°F (200-230°C) (most even on just the base, so the lid handle doesn't appear to be the only factor there).

Given that normal cast iron can go much higher and I wouldn't have expected that heat limitation on the enamel...what is it about the pots that causes that limitation?  What risks are there in going above it?

Comment: The popular Le Creuset round dutch ovens can handle any oven temperature though the lid knob is rated to 500F. https://www.lecreuset.com/round-dutch-oven#ci-heat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its because of the difference of the thermal expansion between the two materials.

Since the [ceramic](http://global.kyocera.com/fcworld/charact/heat/thermaexpan.html) has very low thermal expansion coefficient and [cast iron](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/thermal-expansion-metals-d_859.html) seems to have a rather high coefficient comparatively, then the metals will start to pull apart *too much* at higher temperatures.  The metal expands more than the ceramic under equal heat, so they start to separate and crack.  Apparently, at just above the recommended point, it may start to cause the surface cracks which are common (thanks @TFD).

Answer (score 4):

They sometimes have plastic (cast phenolic resin) knobs on them that are only rated for just over 200°C (400°F), or other decorative trim that is not suitable for high heat due to deformation etc.

They do tend to start crazing (surface cracking) at over 200°C too

The enamel (a special soft glass powder) is fused on at over 800°C (1470°F)

You cannot melt glass enamel on a domestic stove. It would have to get to over 1100°C (2000°F) to melt!

Comment: I don't think its the just handles, because as stated in the q - the recommended temps are for the base only even.  In regards to the crazing, does this happen due to the difference of the thermal expansion between the two materials?

Comment: Surface crazing is certainly related to thermal expansion and would have something to do with it, but this usually happens when over heated above 200°C. But then again it does happen in enameled bathtubs with gas coliphonts, so it may happen as a result of temp and number of cycles

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, the enamel *will* melt at high temperature.

My brother once managed to ruin a pot when making ramen.  (started to boil the water, forgot about it, all of the water boiled off, the pan heated up, the enamel melted, and then when we realized & cooled it off, the pan had fused to the burner)

Comment: I'm just surprised the enamel is that low...craziness.

Comment: @rfusca I'm not sure what the actual temp was ... it was an electric stove on high, with no moisture in it, so it could've been much higher than 450F ... they likely have a safety window as ovens are inacurate & may have hot spots.

Comment: Before the enamel hits Joe's extreme, high temps will also cause discoloration. It makes the pot look like something is burned to the bottom.

Comment: Wikipedia (take it with a pinch of salt) states that these dishes are fired between 750-800 F.  I could see a empty pan on a stove getting towards that on high heat with a good stove.  But that's a pretty hefty margin, *double* 400 to 800, for the oven (and the manufacturers specifically talk about oven temperatures).

Comment: @rfusca that would be 800°C (1470°F), must be a wikipedia error